# What's the different between ad-hoc distribute and share from archive

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to send my application to tester, as far as I know, I can use ad-hoc distribute and I can share app from archive.
What's the different between ad-hoc distribute and share from archive???

share app from archive is means that [image]

Comment: These are the same... May you post also a screenshot for `ad-hoc distribute` as you understand it?..

Comment: @michael-kessler yes, just use different identity. But in team development, only team agent can make ad-hoc provisioning profile, so I do not understand what's the different between them.

Answer (score 0):

In the **archive there is the profile** you used to compile your code, but if you just build using **ad-hoc the profile is not in the .app** and you need to send it separatly.
So the share from archive is easier to use than the ad hoc way.